# how to use scp to copy files and not overwrite files in the distination with same name

Tags: linux, file, scp

I am writing an automated test script that will copy the files from the remote location and make changes to it before copying them to another remotely connected machine.I want to copy a file from a remote machine to my local machine. I am using scp. It was all good until I found out that I have another file in my local with the same name. I either have to change the name of the file in the source or in the destination every time I use scp. I want to avoid this overhead. Is there any hack to just copy the file with the name that we desire to? Like for example:

```
scp filename user@sysname:/path/ dest_filename
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming and would be better suited at https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux

Comment: And no, scp can't do that. Use rsync or unison.

Comment: I am writing an automated test script that will copy the files from the remote location and make changes to it before copying them to another remotely connected machine. How is this not related to programming? I'm sorry I don't understand. Please explain yourself.

Comment: You didn't mention any of that. And I stand by my suggestion to use rsync to avoid the overwriting.

Comment: rsync is doing the work thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy#Function

```
scp user@host:directory/SourceFile TargetFile
```

Would copy the "SourceFile", say, from remote, to the local path "TargetFile".

So you could in theory do:

```
scp bob@remotecomputer:directory/LogonTime.txt /somelocalpath/LogonTime20181119.txt
```